# The Linq SqlExpression query for select list is not being sorted

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have an Linq sql query as given below. But the depot number is not coming as sorted order. I want to show drop down list as depotno order . But it is showed as '1','18','19','2'. I want to show it as '1','2' and so on

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> depotUserList = (from e in ctx.goUserDepartment
 join c in ctx.goDepot on e.DepotNo equals c.DepotNo
 join user in ctx.goUser
 on e.UserID equals user.UserID
 where e.UserID == UserID &&
 e.IsDeleted == false
 orderby c.DepotNo
 select new SelectListItem
 {
     Value = c.DepotNo.ToString(),
     Text = c.DepotName,
     Selected = user.DepotNo == e.DepotNo
 }).Distinct().ToList<SelectListItem>();
```

Comment: Looks like it's sorted as a string value though :) What is `DepotNo` typewise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your DepotNo type is string type, I suggest you could try to order the result after ToList method.

Like this:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> depotUserList = (from e in ctx.goUserDepartment
 join c in ctx.goDepot on e.DepotNo equals c.DepotNo
 join user in ctx.goUser
 on e.UserID equals user.UserID
 where e.UserID == UserID &&
 e.IsDeleted == false
 select new SelectListItem
 {
     Value = c.DepotNo.ToString(),
     Text = c.DepotName,
     Selected = user.DepotNo == e.DepotNo
 }).Distinct().ToList<SelectListItem>().OrderBy(x=>  int.Parse(x.Value));
```